# kbd led backlight not working with Ubuntu 20.10 / Dell E7440 - missing in /sys/devices

Tags: linux

I have spent a good number of hours on and off trying to locate the which `/sys/devices` file gives access to turn on and off my keyboard lights.

Best I can tell, the module `dell_laptop` provides the `/sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight` path, but path is missing on my installation. Presumable something is not detecting it as supported.

On my Dell Laptop/Ubuntu 20.10, it should be `/sys/class/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/brightness` (name of `dell::kbd_backlight`) according to

- https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/x86/dell/dell-laptop.c#L2058

The module is loaded, but there is no device for it.

```
18:42:35  ❯ lsmod  | grep dell
dell_laptop            28672  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,dell_laptop
dell_smm_hwmon         24576  0
dell_wmi               20480  0
dell_smbios            28672  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
dcdbas                 20480  1 dell_smbios
dell_wmi_descriptor    20480  2 dell_wmi,dell_smbios
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_smo8800           20480  0
dell_rbtn              20480  1
wmi                    32768  4 dell_wmi,wmi_bmof,dell_smbios,dell_wmi_descriptor
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915
```

Looking across all the `kdb|brightness` files, has shown nothing substantive, and I tried each unknown ones, but none were the keyboard backlight.

The kernel `dmesg | grep -E 'dell|kbd|backlight'` shows nothing interesting.

This is a list of the paths I do have..

```
17:15:55  ❯ find  /sys/devices | grep -E  'kbd|brightness'                                            
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::capslock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::scrolllock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/input4::numlock/max_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/leds/phy0-led/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.3/0000:02:00.0/leds/phy0-led/max_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/leds/mmc0::/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:03:00.0/leds/mmc0::/max_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/actual_brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/max_brightness
```

Any suggestions ?